# What does adding/removing stocks from optionable to non optionable and weekly to only regular, depend on?

Tags: options, option-strategies, online-trading

Does a company require that its stock offer options as well as optionable/weekly or not optionable/regular? Or is it the OCC that  controls this (depending on option trading volume?).

How often does this occur? If I want to choose some stocks to trade there options, can I be sure those stocks will still be weekly (or optionable in general) for at least two years from now?  Does the optionable and weekly stock list changes regularly during the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a publicly traded  stock offers options depends on the OCC and its member exchanges.

For example, the [CBOE](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/04/072104.asp) has five rules that must be met to list options:

1. The underlying equity security must be a properly registered NMS stock.
2. The company must have at least 7,000,000 publicly held shares.
3. The underlying stock must have at least 2,000 shareholders.
4. Trading volume must equal or exceed 2,400,000 shares in the past 12 months.
5. The price of the security must be sufficiently high for a specific time.

Such rules determine if options are eligible to be traded but the decision to allow option trading still rests with the exchanges and the OCC.  Secondary decisions determine if the stock offers weekly options and/or LEAPs as well.

The only guarantee you have is that options exist, they will continue to trade until existing options expire (barring corporate events such as takeovers, delisting or bankruptcy) or trader interest is so low (trading volume) that they decide not to offer new expirations.  FWIW, the list of stocks with weekly options does not change much or frequently, with the exception being corporate actions.